# Link a button from home page to a modal - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a button on my home page which opens a modal when user clicks on it. I already have a `_modal.html.haml` in `views/index` with tag `#landslide-modal`. How can I link the button to the modal. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end what you needed was to create a button in the view where you wanted to call the modal, because you were already including the modal as a partial using `render`.

Something like:

```
%a.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg{"data-target" => "#landslide-modal", "data-toggle" => "modal", :type => "button"}
  Launch demo modal
```

Wherever you want to use the modal.

Comment: The home page is in `views/layouts` and the modal is in `views/index`. The modal starts with `.modal.fade#landslide-modal{:role => "dialog", :tabindex => "-1"}`. How can I call the modal?

Comment: Use `render` and this way you can add the view that contains the modal and use the `link_to` with the `anchor` option. Maybe like <%= render 'index' %>, or if you want to add just the modal, make a new partial and add it to another file, and render it like before.

Comment: I created a new file to render the modal and call it by `= navbar_link_to '/new', anchor: 'New'` but I got the error `No route matches [GET] "/new"`

Comment: Why the `navbar_link_to`?

Comment: Because the button is actually on the navigation bar

Comment: See the updated answer, if this doesn't help you try the old way, `<%= link_to 'Your text', your_path(anchor: 'your anchor') %>`.

Comment: It does bring up the modal. It's actually a form and when I click on a field it brought up the error `No route matches [GET] "/Click%20to%20open%20form"`. The text is the one in the ' ' after link_to. What does that ' ' actually do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142424/discussion-between-sebastian-palma-and-tri-nguyen).